# Python line to run .jar works very strangely

Tags: python, os.system

I'm trying to run limelight.jar with parameters with Python. Opening a brand new Python 3 shell and entering this:

```
os.system("java -jar /home/pi/Desktop/GGUIv0.8/limelight.jar stream -app Steam -notest 192.168.1.100")
```

Works fine. It brings up Steam Big Pic streamed from my PC to my Pi. Brill!
But here's the thing. I put the *exact* same thing into a Python script, like a Tkinter GUI, and when it gets run it returns a 0 and no stream appears, no matter how long I wait.

What is going on and how can I solve this?!

Comment: Are you putting it in a tkinter script? Can you show us that script? It seems like a threading issue

Comment: I will paste the script in later, but it happens in any script even just import OS and the command.

Comment: Try this: `subprocess.call("java -jar /home/pi/Desktop/GGUIv0.8/limelight.jar stream -app Steam -notest 192.168.1.100", shell = True)`. Just `import subprocess`, it's builtin

Comment: Just like that from python? Does it expect any input or output?

Comment: From the Python shell and a saved script, it will pause for a moment as it does when it would work but then nothing happens, returning to the shell prompt.